# C# Use One SQL Server database on multiple PC

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

I made an application to insert and view data from service-based database (`cDatabase.MDF`).

I have 3 PC, I want to run the application in all PC to insert the data in the same database

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express.

Here are the steps I followed (I'm not sure if they are correct )

1. open SQL Server Configuration Manager to turn on the TCP/IP from Client Protocol and Protocols for SQL Server Express
2. Set local Static IP for the PC. 192.168.1.10 , 192.168.1.20 , 192.168.1.30
3. Set the three PC on one WorkGroup
4. Turn off the firewall on all PCs
5. Change connection string to

   ```
    Data Source=192.168.1.10\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cDatabase;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
   ```
6. I shared my application folder on the network from PC1 ( 192.168.1.10 )
7. when I open the applicaton from the shared folder (in all PCs) I get this error

   > Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

How to fix this error? And thanks

Comment: You will need to create a SQL Server login - either one for the application, or one for each PC - and then create a user (or multiple users) for this login inside your database, and connect to the database using *explicit* SQL Server authentication: `Data Source=192.168.1.10\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cDatabase;User ID=YourUser;Password=YourPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

Comment: @marc_s thank you for your answer, but can you guide me how to create a SQL Server login , it should be done from the C# ? or i should install a SQL SERVER ? i'm using express one

Comment: 1) don't reference the mdf file in the connection string.  Use the DataBase name in the connection string. 2) Use a windows credential for the database, not a SQL credential 3) The computers have to be in the User Group in the windows credentials 4) Set up a Group Account in the Windows User Credentials.  Following these steps will allow Integrated Security to work.

Comment: @jdweng i have done all these steps except first one i didn't get it , can you explain it more please? " 1) don't reference the mdf file in the connection string. Use the DataBase name in the connection string "

Comment: You don't need the mdf file name.  When the database is attached to the server a link is created to the mdf file.  The server than uses the alias name (The database name in the server) for referencing the file.  The remote computers don't have access to the mdf file, only the database name.  You need to install SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to access the database from a remote PC (not from shared folder).  SSMS comes with SQL Server and doesn't require a license.  It allow remote connections to the database.

Comment: @jdweng I'm still beginner at SQL stuff also English is not my first language. so I'm trying hard to understand this xD anyway i think in general you want to say i cant do this with shared folder,, i can only do it by remote PC ?

Comment: You can connect from c# connection string, but you cannot open SQL Server remotely.  Download SSMS on remote PCs.

Comment: The SQL Server application uses localhost to connect a service that is running on the computer.  The remote application can't use the shared shared folder because the service isn't running on the remote PCs.  When using SSMS a remote connection is made to the PC with the service running.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Integrated Security to False in your Connection String.